# Identifying the cause of my DNS failure (domain not propagating)

Tags: ubuntu, bind, nameserver, domain-name-system

I have set up a DNS server with the help of two helpful tutorials:

http://linuxconfig.org/linux-dns-server-bind-configuration

http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/11/07/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-in-ubuntu/

I am using:

Ubuntu
Bind9

and had issues I tried negating on my own thanks to a question I posted here earlier that pointed out my mistake of using rfc 1918 addresses in my previous SOA record:

```
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
 13112012
 28800
 3600
 604800
 38400
);
thejarbar.org.            IN      A         10.0.0.42
@            IN      NS        ns.thejarbar,org.
yuccalaptop  IN      A          10.0.0.19
ns           IN      A                    10.0.0.42
gw           IN      A                    10.0.0.138
www          IN      CNAME                thejarbar.org.

$TTL 600
0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
   13112012
   28800
   3600
   604800
   38400
);

0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns.thejarbar.org.

42   IN      PTR     thejarbar.org.
19   IN      PTR     yuccalaptop.thejarbar.org.
138   IN      PTR     gw.thejarbar.org.
```

I read the ranges that are used under rfc 1918 and modified my routers resource pool to assign LAN devices IP(s) within the 30.0.0.0 range and now modified my SOA to:

```
$TTL 600
@ IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
 13112012
 28800
 3600
 604800
 38400
);
thejarbar.org.            IN      A         30.0.0.42
@            IN      NS        ns.thejarbar,org.
yuccalaptop  IN      A          10.0.0.19
ns           IN      A                    30.0.0.42
gw           IN      A                    30.0.0.138
www          IN      CNAME                thejarbar.org.

$TTL600
0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
   13112012
   28800
   3600
   604800
   38400
);

0.0.30.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns.thejarbar.org.

42   IN      PTR     thejarbar.org.
19   IN      PTR     yuccalaptop.thejarbar.org.
138   IN      PTR     gw.thejarbar.org.
```

I can ping my nameserverver `ns.thejarbar.org`and it gives me the correct isp IP address, but my domain never seems to propagate to my nameserver.

I have searched for a concise tutorial that covers setting up a DNS with a nameserver that hosts (my) or the site. I am fully aware that this is not recommended and am using this for my learning purposes.

Getting to the question, due to the lack of information in tutorials I looked at (nothing about rfc 1918 and no example of swapping these with ISP IP) is my router modification going to help me as it does not seem to be. I have also tried as recommended using my ISP IP instead of the values I posted. My site never propagated to my nameserver. What could be causing this?

I have run dig thejarbar.org @88.89.190.171 and get an authorative response.

Can anyone assist me with the final steps I may be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me that you haven't registered the appropriate glue and NS records with your registrar. [A quick dig on the zone seems to confirm this](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=thejarbar.org&type=ANY&colorize=on&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=auth&nameservers=). As you can see, there are no DNS servers that are currently registered as authoritative for thejarbar.org.

Did you even register your name server with them for delegation? You need to do both of these things if you haven't. If you didn't know this, then I would *strongly* recommend against hosting your own DNS. These are basic steps and you might be jumping into this a bit early.